# WooCommerce: any way to split or clone the tags mechanism inside each product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I have some task related to WooCommerce.

I need to create a perfume shop. And the task is to create for each perfume the "Perfume Pyramid".
Each perfume made from Top Notes, Middle Notes and Base Notes.
Inside each product i want to show this notes based on the notes i will select inside admin.

Each note should be clickable. When the user will click on some note, for example "vanilla" the user will redirect to the page with all the products that have "vanilla" note.

This is similar to how tags working. But i really don't know how to split / clone the tags mechanism so i will have 3 fields inside each product that will allow me to choose the notes for Top, Middle and Base.

Also, if it is possible to upload image for each tag so i can show tag as image instead text

Maybe you can suggest another way then using tags mechanism.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You create 3 [Taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) : **base note**, **middle note**, **top note**

Taxonomies are "*categories*", like *Tags*. You can link the taxonomy to one or many *custom post type*. In your case link the taxonomy to the "*custom post type*" **Product** created by WooCommerce.